# Method annotated with @Singleton and @Provides getting called multiple times

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice

We hava library which uses Guice DI framework.

As of now we were integrating with library by installing it's binding like this.

```
public class Service  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = createInjector(
            new ServiceModule(),
            new LibraryModule()
        );
    }
}
```

But now we want to initialize it using a public initializer exposed by library because we want to integrate the same library with a service based on spring so objects cannot be passed implcitly by consumer service as it does not use Guice. So we want to like this.

```
public final class Library {

    private static Injector injector;

    private Library(SomeClass someclass) {

        log.info("Bean getting created");

        if (Objects.nonNull(injector) {
            injector = createInjector(
                new LibraryModule()
            );
        }
    }

    public static SomeExposedComponent initializeLib(SomeClass someclass) {
        Library lib = new Library(someclass);
        return injector.getInstance(SomeExposedComponent.class);
    }
}
```

and using it inside service like this

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public SomeExposedComponent getSomeExposedComponent(SomeClass someclass) {
    return Library.initializeLib(someclass);
}
```

Now the problem is `getSomeExposedComponent` is getting called multiple times

Actual logs:

```
10 May 2023 20:02:24,245 [INFO]  (main) com.org.service.bindings.ExternalLibBindings: Bean getting created
10 May 2023 20:02:24,247 [INFO]  (main) com.org.service.bindings.ExternalLibBindings: Bean getting created
10 May 2023 20:02:24,247 [INFO]  (main) com.org.service.bindings.ExternalLibBindings: Bean getting created
```

Is there something I am doing incorrectly ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that you are using some overcomplicated approach (that I would not give 100% sure to work), each time at `Library.initializeLib(someclass);` you create new instance of `Library`:

```java
public static SomeExposedComponent initializeLib(SomeClass someclass) {
    Library lib = new Library(someclass);
    return injector.getInstance(SomeExposedComponent.class);
}
```

So, each time you call a constructor logic:

```java
private Library(SomeClass someclass) {

    log.info("Bean getting created");

    if (Objects.nonNull(injector) {
        injector = createInjector(
            new LibraryModule()
        );
    }
}
```

where `log.info("Bean getting created");` prints message to the console independently on the context.

The latter is really misleading as **1)** it does not represent the actual state as you print the message **every single time** and **2)** You are not actually attempting to create a bean, but an injector.